# Make Column take the least amount of space by default - Foundation Responsive Tables

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I am using Foundation with [responsive tables](http://zurb.com/playground/responsive-tables). I have a table with three columns. By default, each column takes the same amount of space.

My first columns and the last column has very little amount of text, and I want them to take only the space needed for the text to be displayed correctly (in one line). I want the middle column to take the other space, because it has the largest amount of text.

I tried changing the width to a fixed width for the first and last column but it doesn't effect the columns.

table code:

```
<table id="tt" class="responsive">
  <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Comment</th>
     <th>Listed</th>
   </tr>
</thead>
    <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td>name</td>
     <td>comment</td>
     <td>now</td>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to set table to use fixed layout: `table-layout: fixed;` - than you can set up fixed width for your first and last column and than the middle one takes the rest of the space.

[CodePen link](http://codepen.io/Akarienta/pen/vEzwKa)

HTML example

```
<table class="foo responsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
      <th>Header 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Item 1</td>
      <td>This is my longest Item 1</td>
      <td>Item 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item 2</td>
      <td>This is my longest Item 2</td>
      <td>Item 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item 3</td>
      <td>This is my longest Item 3</td>
      <td>Item 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS example

```
table.foo {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
table.foo td:nth-child(1), table.foo th:nth-child(1) {
  width: 150px;
}
table.foo td:nth-child(3), table.foo th:nth-child(3) {
  width: 150px;
}
```